# Composer 0.13.0 - Error: Missing id

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a problem with the new version of composer. My chaincode worked fine with the 0.11, now with the 0.13, when I add an asset outside of a chaincode, I have the error:

```
Error: Missing id"
```

Of course, the ID is present in the new asset after the creation ;-)

When I put the analog code in a chaincode to add the asset, I have the following error:

```
Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Object with ID 'Resource {id=zzz.yyy.xxx.tttt#e60e56d92a6928d3f4d1c5bc9bb828c3fc0a292c26ccc35935c594ac0e160c28}' in collection with ID 'Asset:zzz.yyy.xxx.tttt' does not exist)
```

Here an extract of the code (nothing special)

```
return getAssetRegistry(NS + '.ttt')
    .then(function (tttRegistry) {

        // Create the asset
        var ttt = factory.newResource(NS, 'ttt', '12345');

        // Add new ttt
        return tttRegistry.add(ttt)
            .then(function () {

                // Emit an event
```

The identity which plays the code is the default admin user

Perhaps, I found something in logs, but I don'y know how to interpret it

```
2017-09-26T20:09:39.841Z ERROR   HLFConnectionManager    :fabric-client()          [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)) at /home/hyperledger/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:554:15 {}$
2017-09-26T20:09:39.842Z ERROR   HLFConnection           :queryChainCode()         {"message":"Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED))","stack":"Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED))\n    at channel.queryByChaincode.then.catch (/home/hyperledger/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:754:34)"}$
2017-09-26T20:09:39.842Z ERROR   HLFConnection           :ping()                   {"message":"Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED))","stack":"Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED))\n    at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/hyperledger/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:668:34)"}$
```

The only info I found is this post [Hyperledger Composer:: Error: The current identity must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201984/hyperledger-composer-error-the-current-identity-must-be-activated-activation) but, in my case, versions of composer and packages are the same

I can't understand what's happening since I upgrade from 0.11 to 0.13

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where the problem comes from.
It is not a design problem or something wrong with the ACL.

In Composer 0.11, in an event, if you have a relationship to an asset, in your code, you can access directly to its fields
Behavior change in Composer 0.13, the relationship to an element is only a reference, you can not access directly to its fields

Worst, the error is not rised when you call the method `factory.newRelationship()`, it is rised when you call the method `assetRegistry.add()`

So be careful

Comment: I had the same problem. Realised I had an optional parameter and was passing an empty string as one of the object values in the REST request. I removed the key and value entirely, and it seemed to work.

Comment: This answer is still valid for `composer@0.20` (and will probably remain so as the composer won't be developed anymore), thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an issue with the model - you are trying to create a resource which has a required field called `id` and you are not supplying a value for that field.

Do you have a stack trace you can include?

Comment: The only error I can see is that:


`2017-09-27 11:27:36.441 UTC [Composer] Error -> ERRO 3111 @JS : IdentityManager         :getIdentity()            Error: The current identity has not been registered:admin`

But I didn't change anything between 2 versions of composer. Does ACL are more rigorous in 0.13?

Comment: please can you post the contents of your permissions.acl - its possible it is an ACL issue. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the ACL
`rule Default {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "zzz.yyy.xxx.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}`
I tested with a regular user (other one than the default admin) and I have no error

Answer (score 0):

If the Default rule - "All resource:" should be set to "zzz.yyy.xxx.*"

Then deploy your newly updated network and try again.